# Quantum Mechanics - does a paired transition need a perturbation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

I'm doing some theory (to model a device) which, with a bunch of simplifications, wants to consider carrier transitions between extended states in a generalised semiconductor.  In particular I'm after the probability that carrier A will move to a lower-energy state, with the (energy-conserving) consequence of giving that energy to carrier B.  Key point - extended states, not bound or quasi-bound.

My first crude assumption is that this rate is proportional to the product of densities of states of the final state of A and the initial and final states of B, but this leads me still in need of an absolute probability (i.e. rate with respect to time).

So it's quantum mechanics.  I'm a meathead experimentalist usually, and my notation- and matrix-blindness is causing me no end of trouble with reading up on this (believe me I've spent much more time than I can spare!).  Can solve Schroedinger perfectly well (got some awesome plots you'd love!), but beyond that - here be dragons. :-)

My conclusions are heading in the direction of Fermi's Golden Rule, and it very much looks to me that the expression I'm after (for a single carrier transition at least) involves a matrix element ($M$) squared, which is defined as $M=\left\langle i|V| f\right\rangle$, where $V$ is the perturbation potential.  Apologies for any attacks of the vapours induced - having got it right or rigorous is neither here nor there!

My conclusions are therefore that, in the absence of a specified perturbing potential (setting $V=0$ above at all times), that transitions are forbidden.

Obviously that's idealised, but am I right?  Can I stop reading QM?  ;-)

And how would you suggest I proceed?  Incorporate some phonons?  (Best approach?)

Thanks, clever theory people.  You rule.

UPDATE 13/7/2023

I still need a good way to couple phonons to my states, but the main answer is **yes**, you do need perturbation.  Think mechanical modes.  Two masses coupled by springs, movements in 1-D.  There are two modes, one in phase one out of phase.  You can add energy to one (at the mode  frequency (eigenvalue)) and it will not affect the other at all because the modes (1,1) and (1,-1) are orthogonal.  You will not have a spontaneous transfer of energy from one mode to the other.  Now consider coupled pendulums hanging from a string.  You might think these have similar in-phase and antiphase modes, but because of the string coupling, the modes are no longer orthogonal.  Energy will oscillate between modes.

In the case of a system of orthogonal modes, the introduction of a perturbation breaks that orthogonality, and, if you like, energy can leak between modes.  One example is a photon stimulating a two-state quantum system.  The states will be orthogonal when un-perturbed and the occupied state will never change.  Add oscillating electric field from a phonon and the Hamiltonian is modified and the orthogonality broken; the state occupation oscillates.

In the Fermi Golden Rule thing, integrating $\psi_i^{*}\psi_f$ gives you zero if the two wavefunctions are orthognal, but integrating $\psi_i^{*}V\psi_f$ will not in general because the $V$ 'breaks' the orthogonality.  Or something hand-wavy like that.

(by the way, you quantum folks really don't do yourself favours with your 'simplifying' notation. Bra-ket simplifies writing, sure, but we can all read integrals!)

Edit for Roger:

Auger might be a useful way to visualise it, except that I'm thinking about impact ionisation in terms of extended (conduction) states rather than bound.  I've answered my initial question, that transitions DO require and depend on an interaction/perturbation, and have an angle into how I might solve my problem if I can specify that perturbation (based on the simple (well, kinda) example of a photon interacting with a atom/molecule).  The problem has evolved into how I specify that perturbation to the Hamiltonian, and in a very general way what process makes a conduction electron give up energy to a valence electron.

Comment: I think one thing is to understand the physics of the process, and the other is calculating the transition rate (which can be done with different methods, Fermi's golden rule is a possibility.) But the physics is first: why the two carriers scatter, exchanging energy? - there is interaction between them. Is this Coulomb, and are you speaking about something like Auger process?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and reply, Roger.  I've updated the question (added a paragraph at bottom).